# How can I see what a winform looks like at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a winform that is an extension of another application.  Bootstrapping this secondary application is a pain.  I tried rendering the window in a unit test

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShowWindow()
{
   SomeWindow window = new SomeWindow();
   window.Show();
}
```

The window just flashes and disappears.  I tried Sleeping the thread, but that just freezes the window and the visuals are all broke.  There seems to be no `WaitForExit()` either.

How can I test my window for visual appeal?

Comment: How long do you want to show it? What do you want to close the form?

Comment: @David Heffernan - I planned on closing it manually.  If there's a timer I can set instead that would be a cool suggestion.

Comment: Then a modal dialog is the simplest way. You could readily close it with a timer too. Just create the form, create the timer and show the form modally. When the timer fires, close the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `ShowDialog()`. But your test would then block until that returns.

Comment: This worked!  Cool, blocking is not a problem.  I can seperate this test out and run it only when I need to test the visuals.